# Formatar resultado com campo concatenado

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Preciso trazer de meu banco de dados um TIMEDIFF com campo formatado assim: 12:50 (horas e minutos). Utilizo o seguinte trecho:

```
CONCAT(HOUR(TIMEDIFF(Campo.expired,NOW())),":",MINUTE(TIMEDIFF(Campo.expired,NOW()))) AS expired
```

Meu problema está no fato de que quando o horário é de apenas 1 dígito, o resultado fica assim: 2:4 (2 horas e 40 minutos). Preciso exibir esta data corretamente, ou seja, 02:40.

Já tentei usar o DATE_FORMAT dentro do CONCAT, sem sucesso.

Comment: A coluna `expired` é de qual tipo? Como você tentou usar o `DATE_FORMAT`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não precisa usar `CONCAT` pra fazer isso.

Pode ser feito assim:

```
TIME_FORMAT(SEC_TO_TIME(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, Campo.expired, NOW())), '%H:%i')
```

Isso vai calcular a diferença entre as datas em segundos, transformar os segundos em `TIME` e usar `TIME_FORMAT` para formatar do modo que você quer (ex. 02:40)